# Why singleton classes cannot be sub-classed?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I was going through the negative effects of singleton. Here is one of the point that I cannot understand at all. Here is the link and the point.

> Negative sides of Singleton
>
> The following points are used against the Singleton pattern:
>
> They deviate from the Single Responsibility Principle. A singleton class has the responsibility to create an instance of itself along
>   with other business responsibilities. However, this issue can be
>   solved by delegating the creation part to a factory object.
>
> Singleton classes cannot be sub classed.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307233/Singleton-Pattern-Positive-and-Negative-Aspects

Comment: Subclass instances contain a whole copy of the superclass instance. So if you can subclass a singleton, that means there would be two instances of the superclass. That, by definition, is not singleton.

Comment: Can you please share an example.

Comment: Just imagine it logically. Just "make" subclasses of your singleton. Assume you could. Is your base class then still a singleton?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Why *two* instances?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm assuming the OP wanted to make the subclass a singleton too; then there would be two instances of the superclass. If the subclass isn't singleton, then there could be many instances, instead. :-P

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Sorry, I'm a bit slow today, but I don't get where the second superclass instance comes from. An instance of the subclass would only have one instance of the base class. Orchestrating its construction would be a pain, and this seems like a bad idea, but I'm sure it is possible to implement.

Comment: @juanchopanza The first instance is of the base class itself (that's what "singleton" means: you instantiate it once, and once only). If you were able to subclass it, the second instance of the base class lives inside the subclass instance.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young You could still make them both singleton, it would just be a pain in the ass. This statement makes sense: "A car drive. I can only have one car. A Ford is a car. I can only have one Ford." Basically you have completely separate singleton mechanics for the parent and the derived. You can also have "I can only have one car. Ford's and Honda's are cars", where only the Car class has singleton (and if you made a Ford, you couldn't make a Honda (or any other Ford)). I think you **can** subclass a singleton, its just a giant pain in the ass.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams In your example, then, `Ford` is the singleton, not `Car`. If `Car` were singleton, then you cannot have both an instantiation of `Car` and `Ford` and still call `Car` singleton.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yes I can. If I make a `Ford`, it contains only 1 instance of `Car`.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I think we have different ideas about what a singleton class is. If you make a `Car` a singleton, that means you pre-create the one exclusive instance of `Car`. (This is also what I'm alluding to in my answer to juanchopanza.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young (though I agree the design is nonsensical/a waste, as excluding other Fords when you've already excluded other instances of car is a waste of time)

Comment: Try it once and see what happens.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I think are thinking about the mechanism of `static Car static_instance = Car()`. But there is no reason why it cant be `private: static CarFactory car_factory_ = CarFactory(); static Car* car_ptr_ = car_factory_.create_car_from_config(); public: static Car& singleton_instance = *car_ptr_;`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams How are you going to enforce a singleton policy from `create_car_from_config`? It seems whatever mechanism it uses, can be reused elsewhere to create singleton-violating instances. (Just to be clear: when I say singleton classes, I don't mean classes that your program chooses to instantiate only once, but classes that are technically restricted from having a second instance being created.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young the config file can be singleton itself, read from a fixed location. The CarFactory class is private an not exposed outside of Car...and following this logic, I see, you can't guarentee an instance of both Ford AND Honda now. Got it. Makes sense, gonna +1 all your discussion.

Comment: `I was going through the negative effects of singleton.` What effects of singleton aren't negative?

Comment: @FredOverflow:The negative effects are highly context dependent and do not always outweigh drawbacks of other design alternatives. I think discussions on singletons need to be more concrete because such general terms as in this post is really out of scope for this site. People often express their religious belief in this matter and this shall be done elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Buy or borrow a copy of GoF

The original GoF book says the following in the *Implementation* part of Singleton. Note: `Instance` is the same as the Java `getInstance()`.

> 1. *Ensuring a unique instance* [...]
> 2. *Subclassing the Singleton class.* The main issue is not so much defining the subclass but installing its unique instance so that clients will be able to use it. In essence, the variable that refers to the singleton instance must get initialized with an instance of the subclass. The simplest technique is to determine which singleton you want to use in the Singleton's `Instance` operation. An example in the Sample Code shows how to implement this technique with environment variables.
>     Another way to chose the subclass of Singleton is to take the implementation of `Instance` out of the parent class and put it in the subclass. That lets a C++ programmer decide the class of singleton at link-time (e.g., by linking in an object file containing a different implementation) but keeps it hidden from the clients of the singleton.
>     The link approach fixes the choice of singleton class at link-time, which makes it hard to choose the singleton class at run-time. Using conditional statements to determine the subclass is more flexible, but it hard-wires the set of possible Singleton classes. Neither approach is flexible enough in all cases. 
>    A more flexible approach uses a **registry of singletons**. Instead of having `Instance` define the set of possible Singleton classes, the Singleton classes can register their singleton instance by name in a well-known registry.
>    The registry maps between string names and singletons. When `Instance` needs a singleton, it consults the registry, asking for the singleton by name.

The GoF book goes on to show how registries work.

Here's the Sample Code using the environment variable:

> Now let's consider what happens when there are subclasses... We'll select the [subtype] through an environment variable [...]

```
MazeFactory* MazeFactory::Instance () {
    if (_instance == 0) {
        const char* mazeStyle = getenv("MAZESTYLE");

        if (strcmp(mazeStyle, "bombed") == 0 {
            _instance = new BombedMazeFactory;

        } else if (strcmp(mazeStyle, "enchanted") == 0) }
            _instance = new EnchantedMazeFactory;

        // ... other possible subclasses

        } else {     // default
            _instance = new MazeFactory;
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The article seems to be mostly written about the normal Java implementation of singleton, where the constructor is private; that means subclassing is impossible (the subclass is required to call the constructor, but can't). Allowing more access to the singleton means it can no longer be guaranteed to have only a single instance.

It's really an inherent contradiction; if you can subclass, then you can trivially create more instances (by just creating an otherwise empty subclass for each instance you want) so you don't really have a singleton.

Comment: In C++ you can come over the private constructor problem using a CRTP.

Comment: Sure (or just use protected, which is less restrictive in Java than C++). But the second paragraph still applies.

Comment: Sure, I agree. I just wanted to add the piece of information.

Comment: `if you can subclass, then you can trivially create more instances (by just creating an otherwise empty subclass for each instance you want)` -- This argument implies a kind of willful "hacking" to break Singleton. I don't think this is a problem that the pattern is designed to solve, so I think this answer is misleading.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Well, I think it's an anti-pattern; prefer "just create one". But the stated intent is to ensure there can only ever be one instance. If you don't need that - and you almost always don't - then you don't need a singleton at all.